# Preseeding Ubuntu 16.04 for a Hyper-V VM fails to install the UEFI boot section

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi, preseed, hyper-v

I'm building a Hyper-V (on Win10 and Win2016) Ubuntu base image with [Packer](https://packer.io). The machine builds fine and I can boot the exported virtual machine without issues. However, if I create a new virtual machine with the newly created virtual hard-drive it fails to boot with a message saying

```
No x64-based UEFI boot loader was found
```

I gathered from [Ben Armstrong's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2015/02/11/copying-the-vhd-of-a-generation-2-linux-vmand-not-booting-afterwards/) that this has to do with the fact that the UEFI boot files are not written to disk in the correct place.

I have updated my preseed file to generate an EFI drive and a boot drive, however I cannot figure out what to add to the preseed file, or the boot command, to install the required files in the EFI / boot drives so that I can use the virtual hard-drive with Gen 2 Hyper-V virtual machines.

My packer configuration looks like:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "admin_username": "admin",
        "admin_password": "admin",

        "dir_deploy": null,
        "dir_http_user": null,
        "dir_scripts_user": null,
        "dir_temp": null,

        "iso_checksum": null,
        "iso_url": null,

        "vm_name": "not_really_a_vm_name",
        "vm_ram_size_in_mb": "2048",
        "vm_switch_name": "this_switch_does_not_exist",
        "vm_switch_vlan": ""
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "boot_wait": "5s",
            "boot_command": [
                "<esc><wait10><esc><esc><enter><wait>",
                "set gfxpayload=1024x768<enter>",
                "linux /install/vmlinuz ",
                "preseed/url=http://${NetworkHostIpAddressForPreseed}:{{.HTTPPort}}/preseed.cfg ",
                "debian-installer=en_US auto locale=en_US kbd-chooser/method=us ",
                "hostname={{.Name}} ",
                "fb=false debconf/frontend=noninteractive ",
                "keyboard-configuration/modelcode=SKIP keyboard-configuration/layout=USA ",
                "keyboard-configuration/variant=USA console-setup/ask_detect=false <enter>",
                "initrd /install/initrd.gz<enter>",
                "boot<enter>"
            ],
            "communicator": "ssh",
            "enable_secure_boot": false,
            "generation": 2,
            "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
            "http_directory": "{{ user `dir_http_user` }}",
            "iso_url": "{{user `iso_url`}}",
            "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
            "iso_checksum": "{{user `iso_checksum`}}",
            "iso_target_path": "{{ user `dir_temp` }}/packer",
            "output_directory": "{{ user `dir_temp` }}/{{ user `vm_name` }}",
            "ram_size": "{{user `vm_ram_size_in_mb`}}",
            "shutdown_command": "echo '{{user `admin_password`}}' | sudo -S -E shutdown -P now",
            "ssh_password": "{{user `admin_password`}}",
            "ssh_timeout": "4h",
            "ssh_username": "{{user `admin_username`}}",
            "switch_name": "{{user `vm_switch_name`}}",
            "type": "hyperv-iso",
            "vm_name": "{{ user `vm_name` }}"
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "execute_command": "echo '{{user `admin_password`}}' | sudo -S -E sh {{.Path}}",
            "scripts": [
                "{{ user `dir_scripts_user` }}/ubuntu/update.sh",
                "{{ user `dir_scripts_user` }}/ubuntu/network.sh",
                "{{ user `dir_scripts_user` }}/ubuntu/cleanup.sh",
                "{{ user `dir_scripts_user` }}/ubuntu/sysprep.sh"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the preseed file looks like:

```
# preseed configuration file for Ubuntu.
# Based on: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html

#
# *** Localization ***
#
# Originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-l10n
#

d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.utf8
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layout string us

d-i kbd-chooser/method select American English


#
# *** Network configuration ***
#
# Originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-network
#

d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note ignore
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

#
# *** Account setup ***
#
# Originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-account
#

d-i passwd/user-fullname string admin
d-i passwd/username string admin
d-i passwd/user-password password password
d-i passwd/user-password-again password password
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false


#
# *** Clock and time zone setup ***
#
# Originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-time
#

d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i time/zone string UTC

#
# *** Partitioning ***
#
# Originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-partman
#

d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string system
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select grub-efi-boot-root
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string       \
    grub-efi-boot-root ::                   \
        1 1 1 free                          \
            $bios_boot{ }                   \
            method{ biosgrub }              \
        .                                   \
        256 256 256 fat32                   \
            $primary{ }                     \
            method{ efi }                   \
            format{ }                       \
        .                                   \
        512 512 512 ext4                    \
            $primary{ }                     \
            $bootable{ }                    \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            filesystem{ ext4 }              \
            mountpoint{ /boot }             \
        .                                   \
        4096 4096 4096 linux-swap           \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            method{ swap }                  \
            format{ }                       \
        .                                   \
        10000 20000 -1 ext4                 \
            $lvmok{ }                       \
            method{ format }                \
            format{ }                       \
            use_filesystem{ }               \
            filesystem{ ext4 }              \
            mountpoint{ / }                 \
        .

d-i partman-partitioning/no_bootable_gpt_biosgrub boolean false
d-i partman-partitioning/no_bootable_gpt_efi boolean false

# enforce usage of GPT - a must have to use EFI!
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt

# Keep that one set to true so we end up with a UEFI enabled
# system. If set to false, /var/lib/partman/uefi_ignore will be touched
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true


#
# *** base system installation ***
#
# Originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-apt
#

d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server

#
# *** Package selection ***
#
# originally from: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html#preseed-pkgsel
#

tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server

# Minimum packages (see postinstall.sh). This includes the hyper-v tools
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server ntp linux-tools-$(uname -r) linux-cloud-tools-$(uname -r) linux-cloud-tools-common
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select none
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false

#
# Boot loader installation
#

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda

# grub-install –target=x86_64-efi –efi-directory=/boot/efi –no-nvram –removable

#
# *** Preseed other packages ***
#

d-i debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

choose-mirror-bin mirror/http/proxy string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `d-i grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable boolean true` will install Grub as EFI/boot/bootx64.efi, however Grub isn't signed with the Microsoft key, and so this will break Secure Boot, if you are using it.

Another approach is to use this, which copies the Shim + Grub setup that is installed in EFI/ubuntu

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    mkdir -p /target/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT && \
    cp /target/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/* /target/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT && \
    cd /target/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/ && mv shimx64.efi BOOTX64.EFI
```

EDIT:
Note that `/target` is the [file system of the target system](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apbs05.html.en) so this path should not appear in the disk section of the preseed file.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that using the latter approach will allow me to use secure boot?

Comment: Yes it should do. Note that I've edited the code, as what I had before was not correct. I'm also seeing a strange issue where images created from the disk image boot with a black screen, but appear to work fine subsequently.

Comment: I finally tested this and it works as advertised. I fixed an incorrect path in the example as an `/efi` section was missing.

Answer (score 2):

By adding the following line to the preseed file makes GRUB install an UEFI bootstrapper to the `efi` partition

```
d-i grub-installer/force-efi-extra-removable boolean true
```

With that line added the UEFI bootstrapper ends up on the virtual hard-drive meaning that it's possible to reuse the drive separately from the virtual machine configuration.